# consume wcf web service with List<T> parameter by ksoap2

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2, generic-list

there is wcf web service, **EnforceType** is an enum type:

```
[OperationContract]
string TestList(List<EnforceType> enforceType);
```

how to consume this wcf web service by ksoap2?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

this links helped me use ksoap2.They are really ecplicit [this one](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.de/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html) is about configuring the soap objects correctly and [this one](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.gr/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html) is about mapping complex objects into your already defined objects.Hope is helps.

Comment: Please be aware that external links can be broken.  A full answer is always better ;)